# Looping through directory structure to rearrange files

Tags: bash, file, shell, unix, scripting

I have a series of directory (Obj1,Obj2...etc) inside the same directory (Objects). Each Obj directory contains some files. I want to create a folder inside each Obj called GroupA and put all the files that was inside the Obj directory into the Group A directory. I know how to do mkdir and mv on indivudual files and directory, but how can loop through the directory and do it on all of them.

The initial file structure should look like this

```
Object --> Object1  __|--> file1
                      |--> file2
                      |--> file3

       --> Object2  __|--> file1
                      |--> file2
                      |--> file3
       ......
```

The final file structure after the arrangement should look like this

```
Object --> Object1 __|--> GroupA  __|--> file1
                                    |--> file2
                                    |--> file3

        --> Object2 __|--> GroupA __|--> file1
                                    |--> file2
                                    |--> file3
       ......
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some modifications this script can do the work for you, i used to use it to arrange my song by types (mp3, wav,etc)

It starts by getting all sub directories in the main dir (Object), then for each subdirectory it proceed by moving each file or directory to ObjectA previously created

```
#!/bin/bash
#loop over Object sub directories
#tail is used to delete the first line of find output (Object/)
for SUBDIR in `find $1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | tail -n +2` ;
do
    OBJA="${SUBDIR}/ObjA"
    mkdir -p $OBJA
    #loop over subdirectory (eg Object1) content 
    for j in `find $SUBDIR -maxdepth 1 | tail -n +2` ;
    do
            #Here you can add tests to choose which files you want to copy to the new created dir
            #This test is to avoid copying ObjectA to it self 
            [[ "$j" != "$OBJA" ]] && mv $j $OBJA/
    done
done
```

ps: dont forget to check permissions :)

Comment: Thanks,It works! Just a note for others, the last line mv -r should be just mv without the flag.

Comment: You're welcome, yes you're right, actually before modifying the script it was "cp -r", i updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
find Object/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec mkdir \{\}/GroupA \; -exec mv \{\}/* \{\}/GroupA/ \;
```

will probably work for you, but it will give you an error message as it tries to move the newly created `GroupA` directory into itself.

I'd recommend to run it first like:

```
find Object/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec echo mkdir \{\}/GroupA \; -exec echo mv \{\}/* \{\}/GroupA/ \;
```

(cause this way it echoes what it would do, and if you are happy with the results you can leave out the `echo`s)

Explanation:

1. `find Object/` search in this dir
2. `-maxdepth 1` only one directory deep in the dir
3. `-mindepth 1` but at least one directory deep in the dir (so `Object` won't get included in the search results)
4. `-type d` for directories only
5. `-exec mkdir \{\}/GroupA \;` for every found dir create the `GroupA` dir in (`\{\}/` part) it
6. `-exec mv \{\}/* \{\}/GroupA/ \;` and move everything from the found directory to the newly created `GroupA` dir

Comment: this atempts to create `Object/GroupA`

Comment: @Ploutox you are right, thanks for pointing out. I had corrected my answer.